# Report on 2 unrelated objects joined by date

Tags: dashboard, reports-api, joined-reports, graph

I need to create a report with a graph where it shows month by month the number/amount of sales (custom object Invoices) and over the same month how many Cases were lodged. The 2 don't relate to each other at all, other than reporting over the same period.

We would like to see whether our Cases increase if we sell more and have an acceptable % of Cases per number of sales, and an actual % of Cases based on Sales month by month.

Is this possible with SF reports and graphs, or does this need to be done manually in Excel?

Comment: Make use of joined reports.

Comment: Joined reports don't work on dates however, which is why I'm stuck, as that is the only field that I need to link the 2 tables on.